# How can I get and change the property of an unnamed control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have here 1 of 32 unnamed buttons

```
<Button Grid.Column="8" Content="5-1" Grid.Row="1" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
```

all of the 32 unnamed buttons share the same event

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string x = sender.ToString();

   x = x.Remove(0, x.Length - 3);

   //sender.GetType().GetProperties()

 }
```

what I want is to change the background color of the button I clicked. but how canI do it in C# and WPF markup?

Comment: `I have here 1 of 32 unnamed buttons` - delete all that and use an `ItemsControl`. Start reading [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sender is your `Button`(Object) you need to cast to `Button`. Try this:

```
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string senderToString = sender.ToString();
        Button yourClickedButton = sender as Button;
        yourClickedButton.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue ;
        x = x.Remove(0, x.Length - 3);
    }
```